# I Need the row-wise data arrangment of query result into column-wise result dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have three tables `country`,`countrycontent` and `language` and the create and insert statements for each table is shown in following script (you can directly create and insert data by just executing following script)

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[country]([id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  [flagdeleted] [bit] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([id] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY];
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[language](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [code] [nchar](10) NULL,[flagdeleted] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_language] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([id] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 

ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

---

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[countrycontent](
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[countryid] [int] NULL,
        [languageid] [int] NULL,[name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,[flagdeleted] [bit] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_countrycontent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([id] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 

    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[countrycontent]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_countrycontent_country] 

    FOREIGN KEY([countryid])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[country] ([id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[countrycontent] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_countrycontent_country]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[countrycontent]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_countrycontent_language] 

    FOREIGN KEY([languageid])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[language] ([id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[countrycontent] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_countrycontent_language]
    GO
```

---

### Inserting data in all tables

```
 INSERT INTO country(flagdeleted) VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0);

INSERT INTO [language]([name],code,flagdeleted)
VALUES ('English','EN',0),
       ('Hindi','HI',0),('Polish','PO',0),
       ('Chinese','CH',0),('Russian','RU',0);

INSERT INTO countrycontent(countryid,languageid,flagdeleted,name) VALUES
(1,1,0,N'India'),(1,2,0,N'भारत'),(1,3,0,N'Indie'),(1,4,0,N'印度'),(1,5,0,N'Индия'),
(2,1,0,N'Australia'),(2,2,0,N'ऑस्ट्रेलिया'),(2,3,0,N'Australia'),(2,4,0,N'澳大利亚'),(2,5,0,N'Австралия'),
(3,1,0,N'China'),(3,2,0,N'चीन'),(3,3,0,N'Chiny'),(3,4,0,N'中国'),(3,5,0,N'Китай'),
(4,1,0,N'Canada'),(4,2,0,N'कनाडा'),(4,3,0,N'Kanada'),(4,4,0,N'加拿大'),(4,5,0,N'Канада'),
(5,1,0,N'Japan'),(5,2,0,N'जापान'),(5,3,0,N'Japonia'),(5,4,0,N'日本'),
(6,1,0,N'Russia'),(6,2,0,N'रूस'),(6,3,0,N'Rosja'),
(7,1,0,N'South Africa'),(7,2,0,N'दक्षिण अफ्रीका'),
 (8,1,0,N'United Kingdom');
```

---

I need Output of the Query/stored procedure as shown in below image:[image: Image for query result]

---

I have created the stored procedure as follow.

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCountryList 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT c.id AS countryid, l.code languagecode , cc.NAME 
    FROM country c 
         INNER JOIN countrycontent cc ON c.id= cc.countryid AND c.flagdeleted = 0 AND cc.flagdeleted =0
         INNER JOIN [language] l ON l.id = cc.languageid AND l.flagdeleted =0
END
GO
```

Here make sure that,
the no. of languages in languages table may increase
the country in country table may increase

In both case the Query/stored procedure should work properly without any changes.
I mean Query/stored procedure should dynamic.

Comment: See I have update the Question with what I have did.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya see this answer too ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/20070980/1230248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bhavesh I think you want this

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(rtrim(ltrim(code))) 
                    from [language] order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


select @cols1 = STUFF((SELECT  'Isnull(' + QUOTENAME(rtrim(ltrim(code))) + ','''') as '  + QUOTENAME(rtrim(ltrim(code))) + ','  
                    from [language] Order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,0,'')

Set @cols1 = Left(@cols1 , LEN(@cols1) - 1) 


set @query = 'SELECT countryid,' + @cols1 + ' 
            from 
            (
                select cc.countryid ,cc.name as countrycontentname, [language].code as languagename
                from countrycontent cc
                inner join [language] on cc.languageid = [language].id 
            ) T 
            pivot 
            (
                max (countrycontentname)
                for languagename in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '



execute sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: This is exact what I need..!

Answer (score 3):

You can use pivot operator and write a query as:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from [language]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT countryid,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select cc.countryid ,cc.name as countrycontentname, [language].name as languagename
                from countrycontent cc
                inner join [language] on cc.languageid = [language].id 
            ) T 
            pivot 
            (
                max (countrycontentname)
                for languagename in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: @Deepshikha your code working properly but the order of the columns are not proper and column name should be the language code and I need empty cell instead of `NULL` value. can you make it?